# Why does a pointer change address when I call a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in C++.

```
int main() {
    ListaEnlazada <int> l1 (5);
    //l1.imprimir();
    l1.insertar(10, 0);
    l1.imprimir();
}

template<typename T>
class ListaEnlazada {
public:
    ListaEnlazada(T inicial) {
        cabeza = new Nodo <T> (inicial);
        tamano = 1;
    }
    void insertar(const T &valor, size_t indice) {
        if(indice >= 0 && indice <= tamano) {
            Nodo <T> *nodo_previo = NULL;
            Nodo <T> *nodo_actual = cabeza;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
                nodo_previo = nodo_actual;
                nodo_actual = nodo_actual->obtener_siguiente();
            }               
            Nodo <T> nuevo_nodo (valor);
            if(nodo_previo == NULL) {
                cabeza = &nuevo_nodo;
                nuevo_nodo.establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else if(nodo_previo != NULL && nodo_actual != NULL) {
                nodo_previo->establecer_siguiente(&nuevo_nodo);
                nuevo_nodo.establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else if(nodo_actual == NULL) {
                nodo_previo->establecer_siguiente(&nuevo_nodo);
                nuevo_nodo.establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Error: ocurrió algo inesperado." << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error: el índice máximo permitido actualmente es: " << tamano << "." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void imprimir() {
        Nodo <T> *nodo_actual = cabeza;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
            std::cout << nodo_actual->obtener_elemento() << " ";
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->obtener_siguiente();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Nodo <T> *cabeza;
    size_t tamano;
};

template<typename T>
class Nodo {
public:
    Nodo(T elem) {
        elemento = elem;
        sig_elem = NULL;
    }

    Nodo *obtener_siguiente() {
        return sig_elem;
    }

    void establecer_siguiente(Nodo *sig_ptr) {
        sig_elem = sig_ptr;
    }

    T obtener_elemento() {
        return elemento;
    }
private:
    T elemento;
    Nodo <T> *sig_elem;
};
```

Apparently my functions for initializing and inserting an element are working fine. But immediately after the program executes the function for printing, the pointer to the second element in the list changes the address to which it points, and the second element also changes its value.
I already used the debug mode and noticed that after inserting element 10 at index 0 everything is ok, but the error shows up immediately after the program executes the function for printing.

Comment: Immediately after the function for printing, you're about to let your head fall off the stack. Is there code you excluded? And can you do a better job indicating how you know things are changing?

Comment: I didn't exclude any code, except for the headers. Using debug mode, I saw that before going to the printing function, sig_elem in the head of the list has value 0x55555556aeb0, and right after entering to the function, it has value 0x7fffffffdc50. The values it prints at the end of the program are 10 -962292416 instead of 10 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your insert function - `nuevo_nodo` is being declared as a local variable. As long as you're in `insertar`, it will appear to be functioning as normal, but once you leave, your new node is lost and the head points to junk data.

Changing this to `new Nodo<T>` (and altering the references to it later in the code) fixes your issue.

```cpp
    void insertar(const T &valor, size_t indice) {
        if(indice >= 0 && indice <= tamano) {
            Nodo <T> *nodo_previo = NULL;
            Nodo <T> *nodo_actual = cabeza;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
                nodo_previo = nodo_actual;
                nodo_actual = nodo_actual->obtener_siguiente();
            }
            Nodo <T> *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo<T>(valor);  //put it on the heap
            if(nodo_previo == NULL) {
                cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
                nuevo_nodo->establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else if(nodo_previo != NULL && nodo_actual != NULL) {
                nodo_previo->establecer_siguiente(nuevo_nodo);
                nuevo_nodo->establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else if(nodo_actual == NULL) {
                nodo_previo->establecer_siguiente(nuevo_nodo);
                nuevo_nodo->establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
                tamano += 1;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Error: ocurrió algo inesperado." << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error: el índice máximo permitido actualmente es: " << tamano << "." << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
    Nodo <T> nuevo_nodo (valor);
    if(nodo_previo == NULL) {
        cabeza = &nuevo_nodo;
        nuevo_nodo.establecer_siguiente(nodo_actual);
        tamano += 1;
    }
```

This variable is just sitting on the stack. It's going to go away. You probably really need to do a `new Nodo<t>` here.